# Completness property

Tags: real-analysis

A and B are non-empty subsets of $R$.Prove that:
$$sup A \cup\ B =max\{supA,supB\}$$
I tried by defining a set  such that T= $\{a\cup\ b:a\in A, b\in B\} $ and find out sup T and inf T but don't know how to proceed further please help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $c = \max(\sup A, \sup B)$. Obviously, $c$ is an upper bound for both $A$ and $B$ since $c \geq \sup A$ and $c \geq \sup B$, and so $c$ is an upper bound for $A\cup B$. Now assume $d$ is also an upper bound for $A\cup B$. Then $d$ is an upper bound for $A$, so $d \geq \sup A$. Similarly, $d \geq \sup B$. Therefore, $d \geq \max(\sup A, \sup B) = c$. And so $c$ is the least upper bound for $A\cup B$.